# Python: Search for and delete nested lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a tree of nested lists and dictionaries that I need to recursively go through and remove entire dictionaries that match specific criteria.  For instance, I need to remove all dictionaries with the 'type' of 'Folder' that have no children (or an empty list of children).

I am still a beginner Pythonist so please forgive the brute-forceness.

Here's a sample dictionary formatted for easy copy and paste.

```
{'children': [{'children': [{'key': 'group-1',
                         'name': 'PRD',
                         'parent': 'dc-1',
                         'type': 'Folder'},
                        {'children': [{'key': 'group-11',
                                       'name': 'App1',
                                       'parent': 'group-2',
                                       'type': 'Folder'}],
                         'key': 'group-2',
                         'name': 'QA',
                         'parent': 'dc-1',
                         'type': 'Folder'},
                        {'key': 'group-3',
                         'name': 'Keep',
                         'parent': 'dc-1',
                         'type': 'Host'}],
           'key': 'dc-1',
           'name': 'ABC',
           'parent': 'root',
           'type': 'Datacenter'}],
'key': 'root',
'name': 'Datacenters',
'parent': None,
'type': 'Folder'}
```

In this dictionary the only tree that should remain is /root/dc-1/group-3.  The group-11 folder should be deleted first, then its parent (since the child is no longer there), etc.

I have tried many different recursive methods but can't seem to get it to work properly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def cleanup(tree):
    def inner(tree):
        if isinstance(tree, dict):
            if 'type' in tree and tree['type'] == 'Folder':
                if 'children' not in tree or not tree['children']:
                    print 'Deleting tree: ' + str(tree['name'])
                    if str(tree['key']) not in del_nodes:
                        del_nodes.append(str(tree['key']))
                else:
                    for item in tree.values():
                        inner(item)
                        # Delete empty folders here
                        if del_nodes:
                            print 'Perform delete here'
                            if 'children' in tree and isinstance(tree['children'], (list, tuple)):
                                getvals = operator.itemgetter('key')
                                tree['children'].sort(key=getvals)
                                result = []
                                # groupby is the wrong method.  I need a list of tree['children'] that doesn't contain keys in del_nodes
                                for k, g in itertools.groupby(tree['children'], getvals):
                                    result.append(g.next())

                                    tree['children'][:] = result

                            del_nodes = []
            else:
                for item in tree.values():
                    inner(item)
        elif isinstance(tree, (list, tuple)):
            for item in tree:
                inner(item)

                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    if 'type' in item and item['type'] == 'Folder':
                        if 'children' not in item or not item['children']:
                            print 'Delete ' + str(item['name'])
                            if str(item['key']) not in del_nodes:
                                del_nodes.append(str(item['key']))
                elif isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
                    if not item:
                        print 'Delete ' + str(item['name'])
                        if str(item['key']) not in del_nodes:
                            del_nodes.append(str(item['key']))

    inner(tree)
```

Comment: 1) you don't need `isinstance` if you can figure that out from the `dict`'s `type` attribute; 2) in Python it's customary to "ask for forgiveness, not permission", meaning that checking whether things are in the dict before accessing is bad style -- it clutters the code and creates an unnecessary level of nesting. You should just catch the `KeyError`. Also, as is, this will probably get closed as not a real question -- you haven't specified the problem and are basically just asking us to write your code.

Comment: 1)  Thank you for your suggestions.  I will use a try block instead of testing for the existence of keys in the future.  2)  I thought the problem was pretty clear.  I need to remove all nodes with no, or empty, children.  If I were asking someone else to write my code, I wouldn't have supplied my function and asked for help with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest you write a function to walk your datastructure and call a function on each node.

*Updated to avoid the "deleting item from iterated sequence" bug*

**E.g.**

```
def walk(node,parent=None,func=None):
  for child in list(node.get('children',[])):
    walk(child,parent=node,func=func)
  if func is not None:
    func(node,parent=parent)

def removeEmptyFolders(node,parent):
  if node.get('type') == 'Folder' and len(node.get('children',[])) == 0:
    parent['children'].remove(node)

d = {'children': [{'children': [{'key': 'group-1',
                         'name': 'PRD',
                         'parent': 'dc-1',
                         'type': 'Folder'},
                        {'children': [{'key': 'group-11',
                                       'name': 'App1',
                                       'parent': 'group-2',
                                       'type': 'Folder'}],
                         'key': 'group-2',
                         'name': 'QA',
                         'parent': 'dc-1',
                         'type': 'Folder'},
                        {'key': 'group-3',
                         'name': 'Keep',
                         'parent': 'dc-1',
                         'type': 'Host'}],
           'key': 'dc-1',
           'name': 'ABC',
           'parent': 'root',
           'type': 'Datacenter'}],
'key': 'root',
'name': 'Datacenters',
'parent': None,
'type': 'Folder'}
```

**Notes**

- *Walk* function uses three arguments, the child node, the parent node and the *work* function.
- The *walk* function calls the *work* function after visiting the child nodes.
- The *work* function takes both child and parent nodes as arguments so pruning the child is as easy as `parent['children'].remove(child)`
- *Update*: As noticed in the comments, if you delete from a sequence while iterating, it will skip elements. `for child in list(node.get('children',[]))` in the `walk` function copies the list of children allowing the entries to be removed from the parent's key without skipping.

**Then**:

```
>>> walk(d,func=removeEmptyFolders)
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(d)
{'children': [{'children': [{'key': 'group-3',
                             'name': 'Keep',
                             'parent': 'dc-1',
                             'type': 'Host'}],
               'key': 'dc-1',
               'name': 'ABC',
               'parent': 'root',
               'type': 'Datacenter'}],
 'key': 'root',
 'name': 'Datacenters',
 'parent': None,
 'type': 'Folder'}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not quite a correct solution -- albeit elegant: I noticed that `group-11` should be removed -- it's a `Folder` and has no children?

Comment: This: `and len(node.get('children',[])) == 0` is `and not node.get('children')`

Comment: @Theodoros Zelleke: That's because it is not visited. Add a print statement to `removeEmptyFolders`: `>>> walk(d,func=removeEmptyFolders)
group-1
group-3
dc-1
root`

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke: Thanks for pointing that out. Quick fix to the `walk` function.

Comment: Can you explain why you have `for child in list(node.get('children',[])):` instead of `for child in node.get('children',[]):`? I see that the latter does not work, but I don't get why.

Comment: @hughdbrown: The explanation I already wrote isn't detailed enough? If not join the python chat channel and I'll discuss it with you

Comment: This code is beautiful and much more simpler than what I was trying to do.  Very nicely done!  Thank you.